# Can i use SAPI directly to convert Speech to Text from stored audio in real-time

Tags: windows, visual-c++, sapi

What i really want to achieve is this-->
Suppose i play an audio file(using my application) which can either be streamed from the internet/or accessed directly from the local storage.
Now i want to configure SAPI to listen to this source instead of the microphone and convert the speech from the audio to text like it does normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think SAPI supports this itself.

There are some approaches you could use that are "external" to SAPI:

1. Get a [male-to-male miniplug cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000GZ6ZQC) and plug your soundcard's output into your soundcard's input
2. Use [Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm) which basically achieves #1 but with virtual soundcard software instead of hardware.  It can be very tricky at first to understand how Virtual Audio Cable works, and how to use it, but it does work very well once you figure it out.
3. Some soundcards have a built-in loopback feature, which allows you to record what the soundcard is playing instead of recording from e.g. a microphone.  Here are some good info links: [What U Hear](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/20595-what-u-hear-recording-enable.html) and [Stereo Mix](http://www.stereo-mix.com/).  Also try Googling those terms for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Only WAV seems to be supported out of the box - See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717071(VS.85).aspx)

Quoting:

> The wav file input scenario is special because it uses controlled, reproducible audio input and requires a dedicated SR engine, without interference from other applications (e.g., a shared desktop microphone). The file input scenario should use a generic SAPI audio stream connected to the input wav file and an InProc SR engine.